# Does the complexity of mergesort/radix sort change when the keys occupy more than a single word of memory

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

This is a homework problem.So I am looking for hints rather than the solution. Consider a set of n numbers. Each number is 'k' digits long. Suppose 'k' is much much larger and does not fit into a single word of memory. In such a scenario what is the complexity of mergesort and radix sort?

My analysis is - Asymptotic complexity doesn't depend on the underlying architectural details like the number of words a number occupies etc. May be the constant factor changes and algorithms run slower, but the overall complexity remains the same. For instance,in languages like Python that handle arbitrarily long integers, the algorithms remain the same. But a few of my friends argue that as the number of words occupied by a number 'w' grows towards infinity, the complexity does change.

Am I on the right path?

Comment: You are neither clearly on the right nor on the wrong path. You need to go back to the beginning of the whole complexity stuff, there you will find the reason, which lies in the vague definition of the underlying mechanics (sentences starting with "Assuming...").

Answer (score 1):

The runtime of an algorithm can indeed depend on the number of machine words making up the input. As an example, take integer multiplication. The computer can compute the product of two one-word numbers in time O(1), but it can't compute the product of two arbitrarily-sized numbers in time O(1) because the machine has to load each word into memory as part of its computation.

As a hint for radix sort versus mergesort - the mergesort algorithm makes O(n log n) comparisons between elements, but those comparisons might not take time O(1) each. How much time does it take to compare two numbers that require k machine words each? Similarly, radix sort's runtime depends on the number of digits in the number. How many rounds of radix sort do you need if you have k machine words in each number?

Hope this helps!

Comment: For integers that are 'w' words wide, comparisons take O(k) time. And hence the overall time complexity becomes O(wnlogn)? And for radix sort, complexity depends on number of digits in the number rather than the number of words it spans, then its complexity remains the same at O(kn)

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of correct. This is a large part of why most complexity analysis will (somewhere, at least implicitly) state that it's working with the *count* of some basic operations, not actual time. You generally take for granted that most (if not all) of those basic operations (e.g., comparison, swapping, math like addition or subtraction, etc.) are constant time, which lets you translate almost directly from operation *count* (the actual complexity) to time consumed.

To be entirely accurate, however, asymptotic complexity is (should) normally specified in terms of a count of fundamental operations, though, not actual time consumed.